# Creating new transaction scope in a loop performance

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, transactions

Consider

```
   foreach (var myEntity in myEntities)
        {
            using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
            {
                // Some not very important code
                myEntity.ImageUrl = FixUrl(myEntity.ImageUrl);

                MyEntity additionalEntity = Clone(myEntity);
                additionalEntity.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
                additionalEntity.CreatedBy = GetCurrentUser();

                //Step 1
                serverDbContext.Update(myEntity);
                //Step 2
                AddToQueue(myEntity);
                //Step 3
                anotherserverDbContext.Insert(myEntity);

                scope.Complete();
            }
        }
```

Notice that TransactionScope is created inside foreach statement.  Experiment with this code confirmed that transcaction scope is expensive operation.

It is expected that AddToQueue may sometimes throw exceptions.  In this case we don't want any changes to be made neither in server1 database, nor in server2 database regarding that entity.

Without transaction scope this code executes in few seconds, while using on execution takes forever.
What I'm really looking for is to still be able not to change underlying records in case of an exception at any of 1,2 or 3 steps.

Obviously moving foreach inside of *using* is not enough because if at least one pass of a loop fails, than good records may get broken too and nothing will get updated.

What do I need to know more about transactioning mechanism or what other appraches could be tried here?

Answer (score 2):

`TransactionScope` is expensive because transactions are expensive.

If you want a guarantee of consistency, but don't want to make the entire operation one unit of work, you may find the operation completes faster if you parallelise it. A simple way to achieve this would be use [`Parallel.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx):

```
myEntities.AsParallel().ForEach(entity =>
{
    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        // The operation to perform in parallel.


        scope.Complete();
    }
}
```

Obviously this introduces asynchronous processing, so you would need to be careful around any objects you share in the concurrently running loop.

If this isn't an option, the only other practical alternative is to give up atomic consistency and move to a system of eventual consistency. In this case it would mean running without a scope and then performing regular "cleanup" actions to undo any "bad" records which are not in a consistent state.